# How to show preview on a link?

Tags: html, jquery, fancybox

I have a link, on mouseover. I would like to show a preview image using FancyBox and when the user clicks, I want to download a linked file. The problem is that the mouse over is always trapped while the download is never executed.

Here is the code:

```js
$(".my_link").hover(function() {
    $.fancybox(
        '<img src=bla bla>',
        {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'             : 350,
            'height'            : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
    );
});
```

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Is this a regular link or do you have a click handler ? Can we see the markup as well, and maybe other relevant javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you only have one function in the hover, meaning it will executed whatever is in it for both mouseover and mouseout actions. Can you see if you can do something with a mouseout function to close the box?

**Edit:** You can try my suggestion below; the command to close Fancybox is $.fancybox.close(). You can also apply it to your own code if you prefer; just add the second function to hover as I have done with that line.

Also, regarding your use of Fancybox, I haven't used it myself, but I'm not entirely sure you used the function correctly; you pass in an <img src="blah blah"> element as the first argument, but since this is jQuery, I would think you would have to put in a selector such as "#my-img". Correct me if I'm wrong.

If my suspicions are correct, I would try the following:

```
$(".my_link").hover(function(){
    $(this).fancybox(...);
}, function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```